# React Router v4 - Cannot console.log {match.params.id} or save as variable

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';


const Project = ({match}) => {
  console.log({match.params.project_name})
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        {match.params.project_name}
      </h3>
    </div>
  )
}


export default Project;
```

The `project_name` value appears fine within the h3 tag on screen but I cannot log or save that same value into a variable. I'm attempting to take the `project_name` value and conditionally render components based on its value

Comment: That's a wrong syntax to console log a objects' property. ES6 allows you for a key to be logged along with its value for eg: { value } or { projectName }. You need to write your console log as `console.log({ projectName: match.params.project_name });` |  
Also, can you set up a project on JSFiddle / codesandbox.io ? The code that you've written seems to be fine and the issue can't be debugged looking at this.

Comment: Additionally, you don't need to import `Component` from 'react' since you're using a functional component and not a class-based component which extends `Component`.

Comment: Im not sure how to post my entire project onto JSFiddle as its a bunch of separate components and folders. I can however give the link to the github repo , hopefully that helps?

Comment: Also just to reiterate... the value of  {match.params.project_name} is valid and appears on screen

Comment: Yes, github link would be cool. =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180014/discussion-between-sivcan-singh-and-nahmed39).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to log without using the curly brace:

```
console.log(match.params.project_name)
```

To store `project_name` as a variable, simply:

```
const project_name = match.params.project_name
```

Or, you can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like this:

```
const { project_name } = match.params
console.log(project_name)
```

To give a different name:

```
const { project_name: myProject } = match.params
console.log(myProject)
```